# How to protect password and username in Spark (such as for JDBC connections/accessing RDBMS databases)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a use case where we need to export data from HDFS to a RDBMS. I saw this [example](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html) . Here they have store the username and password in the code. Is there any way to hide the password while export the data like we have the option of password-alias in Sqoop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Setting the password**

At the command line as a plaintext spark config:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.jdbc.password=test_pass ...
```

Using environment variable:

```
export jdbc_password=test_pass_export
spark-submit --conf spark.jdbc.password=$jdbc_password ...
```

Using spark config properties file:

```
echo "spark.jdbc.b64password=test_pass_prop" > credentials.properties
spark-submit --properties-file credentials.properties
```

With base64 encoding to "obfuscate":

```
echo "spark.jdbc.b64password=$(echo -n test_pass_prop | base64)" > credentials_b64.properties
spark-submit --properties-file credentials_b64.properties
```

**Using the password in code**

```
import java.util.Base64 // for base64
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets // for base64
val properties = new java.util.Properties()
properties.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
properties.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://mysql-host:3306")
properties.put("user", "test_user")
val password = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.b64password")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
properties.put("password", password)
val models = spark.read.jdbc(properties.get("url").toString, "ml_models", properties)
```

Edit: spark command line interface help docs for --conf and --properties-file:

```
  --conf PROP=VALUE           Arbitrary Spark configuration property.
  --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties. If not
                              specified, this will look for conf/spark-defaults.conf.
```

The properties-file name is arbitrary.

Comment: can you describe in detail how secret_credentials work or share any documentation related to it. Couldn't find one

Comment: Absolutely. Secret credentials was just the name i chose for the properties file. The documentation for the spark submit "--properties-file" is pretty basic since it's just passing through configuration options. You can also choose your own arbitrary names for the options, so you could just as easily use "my_database_password" instead of "spark.jdbc.password"

Comment: I would also warn against loading much data at all to RDBMS' like MySQL via the basic default insert statements. If you're using redshift, you can use databricks' spark-redshift package to make bulk loading very fast.

Comment: But here we are storing the password in clear text without any encryption. So there any way we use the Hadoop Credentials API to store and password then pass it as you suggested?

Comment: @RajatMishra I imagine it is possible to use the hadoop credentials, but I don't have an example of how to do it. These pages seemed most relevant: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/59161/using-hadoop-credential-api-to-store-aws-secrets.html and (partly because I use a cloudera cluster) https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/spark_s3.html#spark_s3__aws_credential_provider and https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/68285/working-with-jceks-files.html

If you get it working, could you post here too?

Answer (score 3):

By passing passwords and secrets as `--conf` doesn't feel right for couple of reasons:

- This might be visible in logs
- prone to middle man attack
- Even if the password is obfuscated, the middle man can use the `obfuscated` string to invoke same endpoint with malicious intend

---

**Few approaches to be more secure**

- Use deployment environment based credentials storage and have spark pull the credentials at runtime from them.
- For example, if Spark is deployed on AWS, using `AWS Secrets manager` or `SSM parameter store` or `Vault`, we could store the credentials. In spark, we could use client libraries like `boto3` to fetch the password at run time.
- During development, this step can be avoided. In Spark logic, we could check for password in conf. If it's not there, we could check cloud provider based secret manager. So only in local box, we will use `--conf` based secrets.
- Another option is to have `env` variable to determine if it's run in local development environment or on cloud and take necessary action.

Answer (score -3):

As you run the application from console using spark-submit, you can access it through Java API:

```
Console console = System.console();
char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Enter your secret password: ");
account.setPassword(passwordArray);
```