# Spark JDBC password in clear text JDBC temporary view

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using a temporary view to load Oracle data in Hive using Spark SQL. Example from the Spark docs below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver",
  dbtable "schema.tablename",
  user 'username',
  password 'password'
)
```

This is working well but having the password in clear text in the view DDL means the password is visible in the Spark Thrift Server log. In pyspark I am able to read the password using `spark.jdbc.password` (as in [How to protect password and username in Spark (such as for JDBC connections/accessing RDBMS databases)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336383/how-to-protect-password-and-username-in-spark-such-as-for-jdbc-connections-acce)) and pass the value through:

```
jdbc_password = spark.conf.get('spark.jdbc.password')
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
    driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
    url='jdbc:oracle:thin://@host:1521/svc',
    user='db_user',
    password=jdbc_password,
...
```

But I cannot find a way to do this in pure Spark SQL for use via Thrift Server.

Assuming it is not possible then it would be great to hook into the credential API. Again I can to this via Python but cannot see a pure SQL way to do it.

Does anyone know if it's possible to avoid having the password in clear text in the temporary view?

(I've reworded this question as I think I originally misunderstood `spark.jdbc.password`)

Comment: I have the same problem (but with Redshift). Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did not find a way to hide the password.