# How to pass .enc password file to spark read from jdbc driver

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, password-encryption

I want to ingest data from rdbms to spark. Earlier I was using sqoop to load the data in hdfs in that I was passing the.

`sqoop import --password-file "xyz.enc"`

I want to do this using spark.read jdbc. I have tried passing the file name in `spark.read(). format ("jdbc") . option ("username":"xyz) . option ("password":"pathToFlie")`

but it is not working. I need some solution to use .enc file with spark read?

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336383/how-to-protect-password-and-username-in-spark-such-as-for-jdbc-connections-acce

Answer (score 1):

> I need some solution to use .enc file with spark read?

There isn't one. You need to un-encrypt the password outside of Spark and pass it as the `password` [option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=jdbc#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc) that you have in your example.